# Are complex indexes possible when using Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, core-data, indexing

I'm working on an iOS flash-card style learning app that, on load, needs to grab a bunch of data from Core Data. But the data I need is a fairly specific subset of the entity, based on user settings, so there are multiple predicates involved testing equivalence. I'm finding these fetches are super slow and, based on research on SQLite, I think an index would be a good choice here.

Now, I understand (largely from reading other stackoverflow questions) that SQLite and Core Data are two different, basically orthogonal things that should not be confused. But it's also my understanding that you're supposed to work through Core Data to do any sort of database work and tweaking; you shouldn't try to bypass and work directly with SQLite when optimizing or designing object permanence in your app.

But the only thing I can find for indexes in Core Data is that one "indexed" checkbox for each attribute in a model. And that's just not doing the sort of optimization I'm looking for.

Here's the fetch request, currently:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SKUserItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"next" ascending:YES] autorelease];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"next < %f", now() + (60.0*60.0*24.0)]];
[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"next > %f", nextOffset]];
[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user == %@", user]];
[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"langRaw == %d", lang]];

NSArray *stylePredicates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"styleRaw == %d", SK_SIMP_AND_TRAD], [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"styleRaw == %d", self.style], nil];
[predicates addObject:[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:stylePredicates]];

if([self.parts count] == 4 || (self.lang == SK_JA && [self.parts count] == 3))
    ;  // don't have to filter by parts; they're studying all of them
else {
    NSMutableArray *partPredicates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.parts count]];
    for(NSString *part in self.parts)
        [partPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"partRaw == %d", partCode(part)]];
    [predicates addObject:[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:partPredicates]];
}

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
fetchRequest.predicate = compoundPredicate;
```

So essentially what this fetch does is sort by next (the time when the given item is due) and filter for username, language being studied, the style being studied (in Chinese there's simplified and traditional) and the parts being studied (writing, tone, reading, or definition), and only fetching within a "next" range. Here's a short list of things I've learned from tweaking and fiddling with this:

1. It always scans the whole table, or seems to. Though next is indexed, even if I force it to search a range which I know will return nothing, it still takes several seconds for the fetch to complete.
2. The predicates, any number of predicates, makes this slow. If I remove some but not all, it's about as slow. If I remove all predicates (thus breaking the app) then it's much faster.
3. The speed is heavily dependent on how many UserItems there are total in the table. The more items there are, the slower this is. Some people can have tens of thousands of items, and that's when this fetch can take as much as 10 seconds to complete. This is leading to awkward pauses in my app.
4. The upper bound on the next value was added not because we need it, but because it speeds up the fetch a little bit.
5. Having the query return a subset of the properties in a dictionary (rather than an entire managed object) and fetching the rest lazily is faster, but still not faster enough.

I'm coming from Google App Engine here, so I'm used to the indexes they provide there. Essentially I want that sort of index, but applied to SQLite through Core Data. I found information on adding indexes in SQLite, the kind I would want, but doing this sort of indexing through Core Data, I can't find any information on that.

Comment: I haven't encountered performance problems with Core Data that show up with 1 predicate, but if you're only talking about tens of thousands of items, you might find better performance using a non-sql based Core Data store. For example, the binary store type might be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out but it appears, testing on my 3GS, that the binary store type can't handle that much data. I got halfway through loading an account with 30,000+ items before the program crashed from using too much memory. Probably because there are 26 attributes in the SKUserItem entity.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad, then. I really don't understand why point #1 is the case if the property is indexed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you want is a **Compound Index** which Core Data supports in iOS 5.0 and later.

You can set it up in Xcode: The *Entity* inspector has an *Indexes* section, or if you're creating the `NSEntityDescription` in code, use `-setCompoundIndexes:`.

If you use Xcode, you'd add a line in the *Indexes* section that says

```
next,user,langRaw
```

That way SQL can use an index for your query.

Answer (score 2):

Core Data has an SQL backend. The way you have done this you will have all the data in one table (part of one entity) and to find the objects you are looking for will require searching through all rows, as you say is happening.

In your Data Model you need to break up some of the attributes you are searching for into other entities. Try and make it more object based and think about what you will be searching for.

E.g.
have an entity for User, Language and perhaps one for lessons or whatever time based thing it is that you are searching over.

The Lesson entity has a to many relationship for Language and a single relationship to user. (or to many if more than one user takes a class)

Then to look for a user's data you fetch that user and investigate her Language or Lessons property to find out more.

To look for a list of users studying a language fetch the language entity you are looking for and investigate the users property.

Comment: I don't think relationships will solve this, unless I don't understand their capabilities. They're not lessons I'm fetching, it's more like a giant pile of flash cards. Let's simplify it; say I just want the Chinese cards for Bob, due before now. But there are also Japanese cards for Bob. And Chinese cards for Dan. There are thousands of each, and their 'next' (due) values are all intermingled. If I got all cards related to Bob I'd have them for both Chinese and Japanese. Or if I got all cards related to Chinese, I'd get both Dan's and Bob's. Right? And how would they be sorted/bound by next?